# Finding Text and Changing Color Across Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fonts

I have multiple worksheets and want to find a string and change the string's color in all worksheets.

The following code works on the active worksheet but is not cycling through all.

```vb
Sub FindTextColorChange()
    Dim iX As Integer
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim MyColor As Integer
    
    FindString = InputBox("Enter Search Word or Phrase")
    MyColor = InputBox("Enter Color Number for Font Color")
    
    For iX = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        Set myRange = Range("A2:D10000")
        
        For Each myString In myRange
            lenstr = Len(myString)
            lenFindString = Len(FindString)
            For i = 1 To lenstr
                tempString = Mid(myString, i, lenFindString)
                If tempString = FindString Then
                    myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lenFindString).Font.ColorIndex = MyColor
                End If
            Next i
        Next myString
    Next iX
    MsgBox "All Selected Words Changed"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(iX).Range("A2:D10000")`

Comment: Modified other's code and missed this.  Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub FindTextColorChange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FindString As String, c As Range, v
    Dim MyColor As Integer, pos As Long

    FindString = InputBox("Enter Search Word or Phrase")
    MyColor = InputBox("Enter Color Number for Font Color")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets         'easier way to loop over sheets
        For Each c In ws.Range("A2:D10000").Cells
            v = c.Value
            pos = InStr(1, v, FindString) 'faster than going character-by-character
            Do While pos > 0
                c.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=Len(FindString)).Font.ColorIndex = MyColor
                pos = InStr(pos + Len(FindString), v, FindString) 'start looking after last found position
            Loop
        Next c
    Next ws
    MsgBox "All Selected Words Changed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Much more efficient and I understand why.